# How to prevent adding twice on booking system

Tags: php, mysql

I have an booking system time, where the user can book a time let say an hour within a specifik date. My question is i cant handle the case when for ex i open in two tabs the site and i try to book a time from one tab and then it displays on the calendar that the booking is done, but since in the other tab the page is not being refreshed and it shows still avaibale the time to be booked and i can book it, so then it shows me two, i mean i can open as much tabs as i can and do the same, how could i prevent this to be able only one time in a specific date to be booked???

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID is relevant to your question

Comment: Verify that the action passes the rules when doing the action. Return an error if something is already booked.

Comment: ACCID is a good aproach but seems general in my case, i was looking for a more specific answer, anyway thanks guys for ur opinions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write some script which will returns aviability of any period by request. Than, in your booking page make a simple Ajax query to check if selected period is still available and run it by `setTimeout()`. If request will shows you that period is already booked you can notify user by showing him relevant message and disable form submition until valid period will be chosen.
this will also helps you in case when someone will book selected date while other user is thinking of it :)